# How Facebook messenger make mobile calls in background?

Tags: android, push-notification, webrtc

How does the Facebook messenger establish video calls when app is in background?

I'm making an android video call hybrid app using webrtc and socket.io, the video calls works fine with app open but I don't know the best way to contact a target user if he's not in the app, my idea is to send a push notification to wake up mobile and enter in the app and then start the video call, the problem is if target user don't allow notifications.

I've already tested calls in messenger with notifications disabled and with the app in background and the call works the same. I can't find any explanation how messenger can start a call when the device is not awake.

Is a notification or a service that allows that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), it's what most people and what Google recommends to use to push notifications. However, that doesn't mean it has to be used to send notifications and it won't be blocked even if notification is disabled. You are able to send data payloads with FCM and handle them on your client with `onMessageReceived` with `FirebaseMessagingService`. For more details, refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages).

Comment: Thanks. Works for what i want, now I'm sending data messages to start the video call when the device is not awake.